# User with page edit permissions does not have New button on site homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, administration, sitepages

A user on a communication site has Contribute permissions to the site pages library. They do not have a New button on the site home page. They are only able to create pages from the Site Pages library.

Is there a specific permission or permission level which is required for the New button on the site home page?

Comment: Try granting **Edit** permissions. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: `Add and Customize Pages` permission level is required to have `New` button, please check if your `Contribute` permission has it, if not try what @GaneshSanap has suggested.

Comment: Please check that another user with the same permissions doesn't have the New button either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try granting either of permissions given below to your SharePoint user account:

1. Grant **Edit** access to user on SharePoint site pages library.
2. Create a custom level permission by copying SharePoint default "Contribute" permission level and select below permission check box. Then use this new permission level to grant access to users on site pages library:

   [image]